# Overwriting the menu break points of twentysixteen in child theme

Tags: functions, javascript, theme-twenty-sixteen

I am currently working on a child theme with TwentySixteen being the parent.

Currently in the functions.js file of TwentySixteen, it has a break point of 910 where the normal menu stops and the menu-toggle button displays instead.

I need to reduce the width of this down to 810 but am unsure how to do this. Obviously i dont want to touch the TwentySixteen theme files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the `js` folder of the parent `TwentySixteen` theme to child theme root. Then add the below code in your `functions.php`-

```
function the_dramatist_dequeue_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'twentysixteen-script' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'twentysixteen-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'the_dramatist_dequeue_scripts' );

function the_dramatist_twentysixteen_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentysixteen-child-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'the_dramatist_twentysixteen_scripts' );
```

Then in your child theme `js` folder (the folder you copied earlier) find the `functions.js` file and make your changes. It will give you the desired output.

Comment: the_dramatist thanks for this, but now its loading both the scripts one after the other

Comment: Can you please try the edited code ? Hope that's gonna work fine. @Will